# How can change virtual phone in AVD in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I use AVD in Android Studio and use virtual phone for project.But when i create a virtual phone it have a lot of Gap space around itself , how can i remove this space?

I use Android studio 2.3.

I want something like right phone with more button in right.

[image]

Comment: Did you checked the "enable device frame" option?

https://abhiandroid-8fb4.kxcdn.com/androidstudio/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Enter-the-AVD-Name-1.jpg

Comment: yes i checked "enable device frame"

Comment: try to enable "Show window frame around device" in extended controls of the emulator

Comment: there is not "show window frame around device" in AVD manager.